# StringBuilder export csv with quotation marks at the beginning

Tags: c#, csv, stringbuilder, quotation-marks

I want to write several csv lines into a csv file with StringBuilder. I enclose every field with quoation marks. If I export the file as a .txt I have excactly what I want **("Artist","Album","Track")**.
If I export as .csv the first field is not enclosed with quoation marks **(Artist,"Album","Track")**. Some test code that reproduces the issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

  string artist = EncloseComma("Artist");
  string album = EncloseComma("Album");
  string track = EncloseComma("Track");

  string newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", artist, album, track);
  csv.AppendLine(newLine);
  File.WriteAllText("test.csv", csv.ToString());
}

private static string EncloseComma(string str)
{
  return "\"" + str + "\"";
}
```

Comment: `EncloseComma` is an incredibly poor name for that function.

Comment: Ran your test code and opened the CSV via notepad, the quotation marks are present for all three fields...

Comment: there are libraries that do this already. try using them instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: And note that that's still not a valid CSV file.  You need to escape any quotes that might be in the actual data.

Comment: Its unclear what "export as .txt" and "export as .csv" mean.  How are the two different, in your mind and in your code?

Comment: What program did you use to open the .csv file? I use excel and no quotes at all, but when I use Notepad++ , all the words have quotes. Your questions is not clear

Comment: @SamAxe the difference is the file ending when using File.WriteAllText

Comment: @DanHunex you are right, I see all quotes in Notepad++, but in excel the first field has no quotes.. weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the quotes will be visible in Notepad for example, it is quite normal they don't appear in Excel or when read with another csv parser.

The quotes in a csv file are only there to enclose fields that could have a delimiter inside them (they don't even mean the field should be treated as a string, quotes could as well be around numbers containing a separator).

To have the quotes still visible after parsing, they have to be escaped with another quote, and then surrounded with quotes to have a quoted field, like this:

```
"""Artist""","""Album""","""Track"""
```

For the same reason, when generating a csv file from code, every field should be checked for delimiters and quotes and those quotes then have to be escaped with another quote.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
    private static string AddDoubleQuotes(string str)
    {
        str = $"\"" + "\"" + "\"" + str + "\"" + "\"" + "\"";
        return str;
    }
```

Just add two more escape characters like `\"` in total 3.